# How to save the results of git show as an excel file

Tags: python, windows, gitpython

I want to save a certain version of the excel file using `python`

I have used `git show` to get the content of this excel

`git show 17ed4f74:xxx.xlsx`

output:
[image]

how to save it as an `.xlsx` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output = repo.git.execute(["git", "show", flag + ":" + git_path], None, False, True, False, None, False)
with open(remote_file_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(output)
```

`git.execute` the seventh parameter:

**stdout_as_string** – if False, the commands standard output will be bytes. Otherwise, it will be decoded into a string using the default encoding (usually utf-8). The latter can fail, if the output contains binary data.